# C# delegated method lost class fields / event lost class fields

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Please help.

I have several instances of Action1 class. Each of them should to navigate to different pages just after completed animation.

Doesn't matter witch object is "Invoked", it always navigate to the same page.

As long as I navigate in "Invoke" method then navigation works properly.

It's looks like "PageAnimation_Completed" is called all the time on the same object instance, why?

Is it something about Stacks and Heaps? How to resolve this problem?

I have following class:

```
public class Action1 : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    PhoneApplicationPage page;

    protected override void OnAttached() {
        ...
        page = (PhoneApplicationPage)elem;
        ...
    }

 [System.Windows.Interactivity.CustomPropertyValueEditorAttribute(System.Windows.Interactivity.CustomPropertyValueEditor.Storyboard)]
    public Storyboard PageAnimation { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Message = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSpinning", typeof(Uri), typeof(Action1), null);
    public Uri Page
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(Message); }
        set { SetValue(Message, value); }
    }



    protected override void Invoke(object o)
    {
        PageAnimation.Completed += new EventHandler(PageAnimation_Completed);
        PageAnimation.Begin();
    }

    void PageAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/" + this.Page.OriginalString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        PageAnimation.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unsubscribe from the `PageAnimation.Completed` event:

```
void PageAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PageAnimation.Completed -= PageAnimation_Completed;
    page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/" + this.Page.OriginalString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    PageAnimation.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've lost all day for this issue.

However I still don't understand the problem - why does it works now?

Comment: Every time you subscribe to an event, the handler is effectively *added*, not *replaced*. So every time you call Invoke, you add `PageAnimation_Completed` to the list of handlers, so it is called every time the event fires, even if `Begin` was called from another instance (I assume the `PageAnimation` is shared between all instances)